# Writing query result to a file in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create a file with those data from my database:

```
4gwJhBY1fG7Ndqk     
L6jNpRcHkvz7B8X     
TQ8NyLZFX21Wp9G     
mFfjBNt6CJyQwTk     
TwN2dfcyQj7hxWJ     
tJ2fGZhwgR9yrdx     
7xDJwPpzBgL8jCT     
zYFVrN8pkj6KWDM     
Xgdzq1rwDx9LjZv     
CBJwvmXTRg7bxYc
```

I am able to echo out every row I want to save to the file.

```
<?php
$dt = fopen("codes.txt", "w+");
fwrite($dt, $code."\n");
fclose($dt);
?>
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this ??? Sql Server , Mysql ???

Comment: MySQL, I binded my website with a database by using PHPMYADMIN.

Comment: You could able to use any application that read from your database and output the result in CSV file that Excel works with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the instruction is here you can easily go trought the images:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-installer-gui.html

Comment: Links are not helpful answers. Please expand on your answer or remove it and post as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into using this, again just a quick Google search away.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-install.html